# How can I change the font size of TOC, LOF and LOT?

Tags: memoir, fontsize, tocloft

I am using

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\small}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepages
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum blablabla...
\begin{figure}
\caption[Example]{This is caption 1.}\label{fig:ex1}
\end{figure}
As can be seen in Fig. \ref{fig:ex1}...
\end{document}
```

But unfortunately, my compiler keeps on telling me:

```
! LaTeX Error: \cftfigfont undefined.
```

What's going wrong here? Or: How can I set the font size of the TOC, the LOF and the LOT one pt smaller than the standard font size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: take a look to the `titletoc` manual page 13 & 14 , you can use `\titlecontents`

Comment: Just added some more lines towards a MEW. Hope that's enough?

Comment: OK, I have found the solution. In contrast to what some comments and pages to be found online state, there is no command "\cftfigfont" in the tocloft-package (at least if it's called by the memoir class). There is only "\cftfigurefont" or "\cfttablefont". Using them, however, only the list entries can be manipulated, not their corresponding page numbers. And I haven't found a solution for the TOC yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memoir includes many parts of other packages, including `tocloft`, so it will be better to search the `memoir` manual for the specific commands used in that class.

Where `K` stands for the name of an item type entered into the contents lists (see `memoir` manual table 9.3), use `\cftKfont` to adjust the section titles and `\cftKpagefont` to set the page numbers.

I tidied a few things in the example and added a bit to test the different item types.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}

% Define a font-switching command
\newcommand{\tocfont}{\textsf}

% Apply the font command to the section titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\tocfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\tocfont}
\renewcommand{\cftfigurefont}{\tocfont}
\renewcommand{\cfttablefont}{\tocfont}

% Apply it to the page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\tocfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\tocfont}
\renewcommand{\cftfigurepagefont}{\tocfont}
\renewcommand{\cfttablepagefont}{\tocfont}

%****************
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage % NOT cleardoublepages
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum blablabla...
\section{Floats}
As can be seen in fig.~\ref{fig:ex1}, the information in table~\ref{table:abc} is valuable.

%*******************
\begin{figure}
\fbox{alphabet}
\caption[Example]{This is caption 1.}
\label{fig:ex1}
\end{figure}
%*******************
\begin{table}
\caption{Letters and numbers}
\label{table:abc}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
A & B & C\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%*******************
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the solution: memoir class overrides the tocloft package. And other than what many internet sources state, you can't use anny abbreviations for K, but have to use table, figure, and so on.